# Deletion of snapshots after 7 days using AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

I tried using the below script to create snapshots for instances having the ***tag*** name ***[Backup or backup]*** according to https://serverlesscode.com/post/lambda-schedule-ebs-snapshot-backups/ && https://serverlesscode.com/post/lambda-schedule-ebs-snapshot-backups-2/
I have successfully created the snapshots with DeleteOn tags as said in the first and second link.The latter part of the second link explains how to delete those snapshots on the specified date. Based on that code, I have the following to delete the snapshots after 7 days.

This is the code :

```
import boto3
import re
import datetime

ec = boto3.client('ec2')
iam = boto3.client('iam')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    account_ids = list('123456789011')
    try:       
        iam.get_user()
    except Exception as e:
        account_ids.append(re.search(r'(arn:aws:sts::)([0-9]+)', str(e)).groups()[1])


    delete_on = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        filters = [
        {'Name': 'tag-key', 'Values': ['DeleteOn']},
        {'Name': 'tag-value', 'Values': [delete_on]},
    ]
    snapshot_response = ec.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=account_ids, Filters=filters)


    for snap in snapshot_response['Snapshots']:
        print "Deleting snapshot %s" % snap['SnapshotId']
        ec.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=snap['SnapshotId'])
```

By doing this, I get the following error :

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups': AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 27, in lambda_handler
    account_ids.append(re.search(r'(arn:aws:sts::)([0-9]+)', str(e)).groups()[1])
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by updating a part of my above code this way:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
account_ids = ['123456789011']
```